# Why do I only see some of my text output when my Window Forms application has a loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

Im trying to provide two numbers, a maximum and minimum, to create a multiplication table. My current code works perfectly in console, but I cant get it to properly print to a text box in Windows Forms Applications. I only manage to print a single, maximum, number.

```
private void MultiTab_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string final = "The Multiplication Table Is:";
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(Max.Text);
    int k = Convert.ToInt32(Min.Text);

    for (i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        Result.Text = (i + "\t");
        for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++)
        {
            string x;

            if (i > k)  x = i * j + "\t";
            else x = j + "\t";
            Result.Text = final + x;
        }
        Result.Text = ("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to change your  Result.Text = ("\n"); to  Result.Text += ("\n"); Every time you assign a value to the Text property of textbox it overwrites the old value. What you need to do is append the value.

Comment: This is essentially the same as your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33073148/why-the-loops-wont-work-in-my-windows-form-application)

Answer (score 1):

`Result.Text =` will replace the entire string, including newlines.

You need to add to `Result.Text` instead of replacing it.

Before the `for` loop, initialize it to an empty string:

```
Result.Text = "";
```

Then below that point, always append rather than replacing, e.g.

```
Result.Text += (i + "\t");
```

Instead of

```
Result.Text = (i + "\t");
```

And so on.

Comment: It's better to use `Result.AppendText(...)` and also OP has obvious problems in min and max